# JavaScript classList property adds class as supposed... but then immediately removes it

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a class into the DOM using vanilla JavaScript, I can get my program to work but for some reason it removes the class right immediately after it is added.

Here's my HTML.

```
<div class="form-group step-container clearfix" id="steps">
    <h1>1</h1>
    <h1>2</h1>
</div>
<button id="hsbcFormNext" class="hsbc-btn margin-right-input">Siguiente</button>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("hsbcFormNext").addEventListener("click", formTwo);    
};

var formTwo = function() {
    document.getElementById("steps").classList.add("step-two");
};
```

Like I said the program does add the class, but then immediately removes it.

Comment: [This](http://codepen.io/shadowfacts/pen/yaBBWJ) works fine for me, is there perhaps something else that is causing the class to be removed?

Comment: Your code works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/h8bwf1wa/

Comment: There is not problem with this code as it is, the code that's causing the problem is not here.

Comment: Is there some other type of JavaScript than vanilla JavaScript? Are you referring to strawberry JavaScript perhaps?

Comment: If you're not sure what is changing the class, you can break on attribute modifications in the Chrome Dev Tools https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints#dom

Comment: Is your sample HTML inside a `FORM`? If so default type for `button` element is `submit`. In a nutshell your form is submitted to a server and page is reloaded.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev You're the real MVP. Changed it to an anchor element and it worked like a charm.